# HyperLink to Radiobutton css js

Tags: css, hyperlink, radio-button

How can we activate a radio button by clicking a link in the document?

Thanks

*(I read a few articles on the question. It seems to be possible although contradictory statements. No solution found)*

Comment: You need a Script such as JS that listen to a click on that link and checks a value then. Basically: `.anchorElement.addEventListener('click', function() { inputElement.checked = true })`

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="radio" id="myRadio" name="myRadioGroup" value="option1"> Option 1

<a href="#" onclick="activateRadio()">Activate Radio Button</a>

<script>
function activateRadio() {
  var radio = document.getElementById("myRadio");
  radio.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attribute anymore. In 2023 it is standard to use an event listener to split JS and HTML and make maintenance easier

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).